# NodeJS Modbus Master Read From multiple IP Adresses

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, modbus

I'm working in a modbus project using the jsmodbus (https://github.com/Cloud-Automation/node-modbus) module and this way, I can use the readHoldingRegister function:

```
var modbus = require('jsmodbus');

function read(station, callback){
var client = modbus.client.tcp.complete({ 
            'host'              : station.ipAdress, 
            'port'              : station.port, //502
            'autoReconnect'     : true,
            'reconnectTimeout'  : 1000,
            'timeout'           : 5000,
            'unitId'            : 0
        });

client.connect();
    client.on('connect', function () {
        client.readHoldingRegisters(startReg, endReg).then(function (resp) {
            return callback(resp); 
        }).fail(console.log);
    });
    client.on('error', function (err) {
        retrun callback(null);
    });
}
```

I need to do this for how many IPs I have and push each "resp" result in an array "allResults" and then return it, but I'm not getting the result when I put the code above in a for loop neither async.each.

```
readAll(ip_adresses, (allResults) => {
     doSomethingWith(allResults);
});
```

what is the right way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below

```
var async = require('async');
...
function read(station, callback) {
    ...
}

async.map(ips, read, function(err, results) {
    if (err)
        return console.log(err);
    ...
    // Process results
})
```

Comment: Sorry for off-track Q
Need to know I have one serial IP modem device in which I can set my TCP/IP address. how to receive data with help of nodejs.

Comment: You can use `net`-module to exchange with raw data or `http`-module. In any case you need to know a message protocol of your device. P.S. I don't have any idea what is a serial IP modem is.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap **read** in promise

```
function read(station) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     ...
     client.readHoldingRegisters(startReg, endReg).then(function (resp) {
        // here is the point
        // in every promise, after resolve, the result will transform to `then` function
        // and you will get the result via `read(station).then(result)`
        return resolve(resp); 
     }).fail(console.log)
  });
}

function readAll(stations) {
  // the stations contain multiple ip, such as [ip1, ip2, ip3...]
  // the map function transform every ip to a promise
  // use Promise.all to run every promise
  // and then, get the results
  var readTasks = stations.map(read);
  Promise.all(readTask)
    .then(allResults => {
      doSomethingWith(allResults);
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you provide a little more explanation of how this works? Thank you!

Comment: @halsn, actually, I did something very similar. As client.readHoldingRegisters is already promisified, I could push it in array and used Promise.all directly.

The only problem for my was the legacy system, that used async. So, this method needed to have an callback. So, I used Promise.all.asCallback and everything worked well.

Anyway, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Sorry for off-track Q
Need to know I have one serial IP modem device in which I can set my TCP/IP address. how to receive data with help of nodejs.